# How to Read/Write file from USB pen drive in android

Tags: android, usb-drive

I created an application which is having database.I want to copy,update the database my reading and writing USB Pen Drive database.I dont know how to detect following things.

```
1) How to check android phone support OTG(Pen drive support) from application itself without using any 3rd party Application. 
2) Check USB pen drive is connected to Android Phone or not.
3) Read the File if it is already exist on Pen drive.(without using any 3rd party Application)
4) Write the File to Pend drive.(without using any 3rd party Application)
```

I want to know from where to start.

Comment: Refer this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html & also refer this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html

Comment: Thanks,Is there any tutorial or example link for reference.Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/use-intent-filter-to-detect-specified.html

Comment: http://mobilemerit.com/android-app-for-usb-host-with-source-code/

Comment: have you got any solution @LalitJadiya